# How to set a default text editor for PowerShell (e.g. Visual Studio Code)

Tags: powershell, text-editor, windows-terminal

I am using the new [windows terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).
I just installed [powershell v7.0.2](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.0.2) and [starship](https://github.com/starship/starship) to make it better.

I want to edit the `starship` config, so I ran this command:

```sh
> starship.exe config
----------------------
Error: editor "vi" was not found. Did you set your $EDITOR or $VISUAL environment variables correctly?
Full error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }
```

So I went ahead and edited my `$PROFILE` to set `visual studio code` as the default editor (`code` is in the path):

```
> code $PROFILE
---------------
$ENV:EDITOR = "code"
$ENV:VISUAL = "code"
```

Now I get the same error but with `code` instead of `vi`:

```
> starship.exe config
----------------------
Error: editor "code" was not found. Did you set your $EDITOR or $VISUAL environment variables correctly?
Full error: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "The system cannot find the file specified." }
```

---

The reason I ended up running `starship config` is because after creating the `$HOME\.starship\starship.toml` config file, `starship` ignores it, although I've set the path in my profile:

```
> code $PROFILE
---------------
$ENV:STARSHIP_CONFIG = "$HOME\.starship"
```

So I ran `starhip config` to see which is the path that it expects the `config file` to be in.

---

I also tried to set the full path to `visual studio code` in `$EDITOR`, but it didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1110795/how-do-i-make-notepad-my-default-editor-in-powershell

Comment: @NicklausBrain I came across that when I was searching, and It did not help me, how would you apply that  solution to my problem?

Comment: Why not just open Explorer, right-click (SomeFileNmae.ps1, SomeFileName.txt, SomeFileName.log, SomeFileName.ini, SomeFileName.config, etc...) the file of the type you want, and change the app association to VSCode, then double-clicking the file will start VSCode with that file or typign what you did to get the same result.

Comment: @postanote as I explained above, the reason why I am doing this in the first place is because the `starship.toml` config file (which I created in the documented path) seams to be ignored by `starship` and I wanted to open in through the `starship config` command so I can see the actual filename and path that it expects to find the config in.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, and managed to solve it by setting the $EDITOR variable to the absolute path of your editor, so for Visual Studio Code, add this to your $PROFILE:

```
$ENV:EDITOR = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised code isn't in your path:

```
$env:path += ";C:\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
```

Comment: `code` is already in my path. As you can see above, I invoke it from powershell and it works. The problem is when I run `starship config` having configured `$end:editor = code`, `starship` itself does not seam to be able to invoke `code` and it gives an error.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean, default program to open ps1?
If so it's a registry entry, HKLM and find extension...

Comment: No, I mean the default `text editor` to be used by different tools which require you at some point to edit a file. In my case, it is `starship config` which should open the `starship.toml` config file with that `default text editor`. Other examples are: `git config -e` and `git commit`.